# How to change the order of registered scripts in a ScriptManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

### Background

Within our master page we have a `ScriptManager` that looks something like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="False" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/master.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

I'm registering additional scripts in nested controls on pages by doing the following

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, this.GetType(), "jquery-ui", "~/js/jquery-ui.js");
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

### Expected

1. master.js
2. jquery-min.js
3. jquery-ui.js *

### Actual

1. jquery-ui.js *
2. master.js
3. jquery-min.js

### Question

Is there any way to change the order the registered scripts are loaded in?

*- or -*

Is it possible to at least ensure the scripts that are registered in the actual `ScriptManager` block are registered prior to code-behind registered scripts?

Comment: Just genarate script full html script block yourself anywhere in your page, it's easier that to look throught heavy asp.net control

Comment: Sadly that isn't a solution; the reason behind using the `ScriptManager` is to prevent duplicate references to the same JavaScript file. By using the script manager, it alleviates this problem, although ironically opens another can of problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging a bit into `ScriptManager` source code we can make two useful observations:

- Scripts added to the manager are registered on the page one by one in order they appear in the collection `ScriptManager.Scripts` (if you are curious - via method `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, not in the `Render` method or smth like that).
- Scripts declared in the markup will be added to the collection `ScriptManager.Scripts` upon `ScriptManager` object creation.

Therefore a way to

> ensure the scripts that are registered in the actual ScriptManager block are registered prior to code-behind registered scripts

is to add your scripts in controls directly into `ScriptManager.Scripts` collection instead of using static utility methods of `ScriptManager` class. Control's code sample follows:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager currentScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    if (currentScriptManager != null)
    {
        ScriptReference scriptRef = new ScriptReference("~/js/jquery-ui.js");
        currentScriptManager.Scripts.Add(scriptRef);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
            this.GetType(), "jquery-ui", "js/jquery-ui.js");
    }

    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

One small note - as can be seen in the code sample I would recommend handle case when there is no `ScriptManager` on the page.

Comment: Nice answer @Andrei, thank you. Couple of quick questions; by adding them explicitly to the scripts collection, will that deem the naming (and thus the prevention of duplicate scripts) redundant? And secondly, how did you view the source? :)

Comment: @Richard, this code still uses `ScriptManager` and its collection of scripts, we just changed the way scripts are added to it. `ScriptManager` object still presents on the page, and still takes care about duplicates. As to the source - there are many decompilers around. Personally I use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx).

Answer (score 1):

In your pages, use `<asp:ScriptManagerProxy>` to register your scripts and they'll appear in the expected order. Scripts registered in code-behind are added to the script manager before the ASPX is even parsed.

Comment: I always wondered what ScriptManagerProxy was for. This is a much better solution than the accepted answer.