# Asp.net C# show Catch error on data insert to database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to insert data to data base but i want to show an alert message if the data is not inserted or any other expectation from data base at that time a tying to show alert in catch but it is not showing up and on `finally` is working fine.

```
        try
        {
            using (var con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into time_table (`year`, `Day`) values(@id, @REG)";
                con.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    TextBox txtUsrId = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtStudent_Name");
                    TextBox REGId = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtreg_number");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsrId.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@REG", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = REGId.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch 
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('Error Contact Admin')", true);
        }
        finally {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('recorded added')", true);
        }
```

Comment: in finally, use string "alert_finally or something different form "alert"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts in `ScriptManager` are identified by it's type and it's key. Your problem is because in `catch` and in `finally` you wrote two identical keys - `"alert"`. To achieve expected behavior use different keys, for ex.  `"alert_catch"` and  `"alert_finally"`

Comment: Thanks worked but there on catch that shows the alert perfect after that it is showing the fineally alert also wat to do for that

Comment: @Shaik Try to find answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121251/how-to-change-the-order-of-registered-scripts-in-a-scriptmanager

Comment: put the finally alert  just after loop code ending.  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                } // here

Answer (score 0):

If you Used Update Panels Then You can Use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();", true);
```

Other Wise You can Use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();",true);
```